# Using R to scrape JavaScript-heavy webpage

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, v8, rvest

I am looking to scrape publicly available descriptions of parcels of land in R using Rvest and V8. However, I am having a hard time getting past the JavaScript on the page as it is highly dynamic. This is the code I have so far:

```
GISurl <- "https://hosting.tighebond.com/plainfieldct_public/##info-address"

GIS <- read_html(GISurl)

owners <- GIS %>% html_nodes("div.owner") %>% html_text()

# Create a new v8 context
ct <- v8()

#parse the html content from the js output and print it as text
read_html(ct$eval(gsub('document.write','', owners))) %>% html_text()
```

I keep getting an error message that reads:

> Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context, serialize) : ReferenceError: parcel is not defined.

To my understanding, the message is popping up because R doesn't know which parcel of land I'd like data from. How would I go about pulling data from ALL of the parcels (instead of specific pre-determined ones)?

Comment: First make this specific to getting one. Should there not be an id to use for name or address or parcel id to use for testing?

Comment: There is, but if you go to the url you'll see that you have to manually click on each parcel to gather that information. I am looking for a way to scrape all of this information without having to click on individual parcels. Otherwise I'll end up manually clicking on each parcel, which is what I was writing the script to avoid doing